# React Route Path Parameter and Redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to have a parameter in front of the path.

Currently, I only have exact path.

```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
      <Route exact path='/member' component={Member} />
      <Route exact path='/league' component={League} />
      <Route exact path='/fixture' component={Fixture} />
      <Route exact path='/user' component={User} />
    </Switch>


    <navLink to='/member' activeClassName='active'>
    </navLink>
```

I would like to have something like redirecting feature and render param's component.

1. An user comes in with url www.example.com/clubname1
2. Once clicking NavLink to='/member', it redirects to (www.example.com/clubname1/mebmer) and
   uses clubname1 as a parameter and renders corresponding member data.
3. Same features for league and fixture.

How can I implement above feature by modifying NavLink or Route.

Answer (score 0):

At first, your route will be like bellow

```
<Route path="/:id/member" component={Member} />
```

Here `:id` is your desired parameter.

Nowhen you call the route using `NavLink` will be like bellow

```
<NavLink to="/10231/member">Member</NavLink>
```

So here `10231` is your parameter

and you can access the parameter like bellow

```js
export function Member(props) {
  return (
    <h1>
      I am your memeber id {props.match.params.id} componenet. write your code
      here
    </h1>
  );
}
```

Here `{props.match.params.id}` this is your parameter.